# QT small image of opengl graphics

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtwidgets

I have to small zone in left bottom corner for openGl painting. Im use QT widget.
[image]

```
void GraphWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glColor3f( 1 ,1 , 0 );

    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
        glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5 );
        glVertex2f( 0.5, 0.5 );
        glVertex2f( -0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();
}
```

I need to increase area of 'canvas' of opengl view.

Comment: What are you asking? What is the actual question? Is the problem that the area is too small and you thought it would be larger? If so, we'll need to see how you set up OpenGL. Please describe the problem in more detail and supply more code related to the problem.

Comment: I need to increase area of 'canvas' of opengl view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are creating "canvas" of opengl view. In Qt, OpenGL only knows about the surface it needs to draw into, based on the Qt widget it is a part of. In your case, it appears that the widget itself is sized smaller than the mainwindow. So check how the widget you are drawing into, is created and sized. If you can share the code of the initialisation of the widget and how it is positioned in the mainwindow, it will be useful.

Comment: @YYY Had this same problem myself. Just borrowed your glViewport() answer. 
How can we get a hold of the current window's size so that parameters w and h are always as big as the canvas itself.